# RegistryKeyPremissionsCheck and LocalMachine does not exist in current context

Tags: c#, registry

I tried to write a simple C# program with UI to add my own key and value in registry. I was adding it to registry so that my program can read it later when it starts and does not reconfigure itself.

```
RegistryKey rk =  LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\AMC", RegistryKeyPremissionsCheck.ReadWriteSubTree, RegistryRights.ChangePermissions | RegistryRights.ReadKey);//Get the registry key desired with ChangePermissions Rights.
RegistrySecurity rs = new RegistrySecurity();
rs.AddAccessRule(new RegistryAccessRule("Administrator", RegistryRights.FullControl, InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit | InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit, PropagationFlags.InheritOnly, AccessControlType.Allow));//Create access rule giving full control to the Administrator user.
rk.SetAccessControl(rs); //Apply the new access rule to this Registry Key.
rk = LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\AMC", RegistryKeyPremissionsCheck.ReadWriteSubTree, RegistryRights.FullControl); // Opens the key again with full control.
rs.SetOwner(new NTAccount("Administrator"));// Set the securitys owner to be Administrator
rk.SetAccessControl(rs);// Set the key with the changed permission so Administrator is now owner.
```

This is the code I picked up from some question at Stackoverflow. I was trying to resolve permission issue while adding/deleting/modifying the keys.

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in you first line you are using `RegistryKeyPremissionsCheck` which is a variable you haven't defined yet. same goes to `LocalMachine`.
write the line

```
RegistryKey LocalMachine = Registry.LocalMachine;
```

before your code for `LocalMachine`

as for `RegistryKeyPremissionsCheck.ReadWriteSubTree` replace it with `true` if you want to edit the values under the sub key you are opening, otherwise you can put `false` there

if you just want to add key to the registry i would just use -

```
int MyNumber = 0; // Your value, doesnt have to be a number
Registry.SetValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\AMC", "My User Name", MyNumber);
```

and to get the value

```
object val = Registry.GetValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\AMC", "My User Name", -1);
```

now i put this code and it works if you have the correct permissions (you are the administrator)

```
RegistryKey LocalMachine = Registry.LocalMachine;
         RegistryKey rk = LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\AMC",
            RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree, RegistryRights.ChangePermissions | RegistryRights.ReadKey);//Get the registry key desired with ChangePermissions Rights.
         RegistrySecurity rs = new RegistrySecurity();
         rs.AddAccessRule(new RegistryAccessRule("Administrator", RegistryRights.FullControl, InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit | InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit, PropagationFlags.InheritOnly, AccessControlType.Allow));//Create access rule giving full control to the Administrator user.
         rk.SetAccessControl(rs); //Apply the new access rule to this Registry Key.
         rk = LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\AMC",
            RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree, RegistryRights.FullControl); // Opens the key again with full control.
         rs.SetOwner(new NTAccount("Administrator"));// Set the securities owner to be Administrator
         rk.SetAccessControl(rs);
         int MyNumber = 0; // Your value, doesn't have to be a number
         rk.SetValue("username", MyNumber);// The username should by the dynamic part
```

Comment: Many Thanks!! It worked.. LocalMachine is now avaliable. What I want is to store a key pair value for a user on system. for another user it would be another tree in registry. So what I want is to add few keys in registry and save. Please help further on permisions..

Comment: If it helps, I am running this on windows 7, 32 bit.

Comment: did not worked :( Object reference not set to an instance of an object at first  rk.SetAccessControl(rs);

Comment: it says NullReferenceException was unhandled.

Comment: it's because you are trying to address "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\AMC" that you need to create before you try to go there... i though you already created that before trying to go there

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34365/discussion-between-ravi-kumar-gupta-and-no-idea-for-name)